# How can Transfer ETH with Privatekey?

Tags: private-key, signtransaction

can you give me some examples of how I can send ETH from wallet A to wallet B? I have a 64 digit private key.

Preferably a script that works so that I can slowly familiarize myself with it. I'm already working through the community posts here to learn :)